# ¿Cómo soluciono este error al querer Insertar fecha a Mysql con timestamp?

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

He creado un campo para insertar la hora y fecha actual pero al momento de enviar a la base de datos tengo un error y no comprendo cual es, por favor su ayuda.

> índice indefinido: fecha en C: \ wamp \ www \ select \ index.php en la línea 45.

```
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set('bogota-Lima-Quito');
$fecha_actual=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

     ?>


    <form  action="index.php" method="POST">

        <label for="txtnombre">Nombres:</label><input type="text" name="txtnombre">
        <label for="curso">Curso:</label>
        <select name="curso">
            <option value="matematica">matematica</option>
            <option value="lenguaje">lenguaje</option>
            <option value="quimica">quimica</option>
        </select>

        <label for="txtnombre">Fecha:</label><input type="datetime" name="fecha" value="<?= $fecha_actual?>">
        <input type="submit" name="guardar" value="guardar">

    </form>
</body>
</html>


<?php


mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('curso') or die (mysql_error());




if (@$_POST['guardar']) {

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO alumno (nombre,nivel,fecha) VALUES('$_POST[txtnombre]','$_POST[curso]','$_POST[fecha]')");
}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede que al recibir el dato de la fecha no este formateada correctamente...

Prueba a forzar el formato de la fecha

```
$fecha=date ("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($_post["fecha"]));
mysql_query("INSERT INTO alumno (nombre,nivel,fecha) VALUES('$_POST[txtnombre]','$_POST[curso]','$fecha'");
```

Eso por un lado, por otro lado yo modificaría la condición en plan:

```
if (isset($_POST['guardar'])&&$_POST['guardar']!="") {
```

Ya me dirás si te funciona o el error que te da....

Comment: estimado le comento que funcionó correctamente le agradezco infinitamente por su tiempo y el poder ayudarme, que tenga un excelente día.

Comment: @ccZero si la respuesta te sirvió considera marcarla como aceptada esa es la mejor forma de dar las gracias 

Comment: @Aprendiz ¿Cuál es la opción aceptada o como es? por favor estimado.

Comment: @ccZero Si esta respuesta te sirvio, entonces del lado izquierdo de la misma existe el ícono de una *palomita* que al presionar se pone verde y eso a quien te respondió le da 15 de reputación y a ti 2 por aceptarla, al resto de la comunidad nos indica que esto solucionó el problema

Comment: @Aprendiz Gracias estimado un excelente día, nada más para comentarles que pase un buen tiempo buscando el error y no lo encontraba, gracias a todos por la valiosa ayuda.